# Problems with firewall when forwarding 8080 thru Comtrend5071T

Tags: firewall, port-forwarding, linksys, socket, ip-routing

I am trying to forward port 8080 thru my modem but i have not been successful. to be exact my desired route is as follows:

- Connection to Server A (192.168.0.5) is tested as working (192.168.0.5:8080)
- Server A (192.168.0.5) forwards thru Linksys router (tested as working (172.16.1.2:8080))
- Linksys router (172.16.1.2) forwards thru CT5701T (tested  as *not* working (174.34.0.58:8080) while inside subnet, BUT works on the outside)

the NAT routing info for CT5071T is:

```
Server Name         = Web Server
External Port Start = 8080
External Port End   = 8080
Protocol            = TCP
Internal Port Start = 8080
Internal Port End   = 8080
Server IP Address   = 172.16.1.2
```

CT5071T was rebooted after make this change.

Comment: How are you testing the port forwarding?  Are you trying to do it from your computer inside your firewall?

Comment: @smassey just tested from outside of my subnet (via 3G) and is tested as working, which firewall would be causing this to happen?

Comment: Many "SOHO" WAN/LAN routers that implement port forwarding will not forward traffic originating from the "LAN" side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem that caused my server to not be seen was that my router is in fact a SOHO router that does not forward ports back into the subnet (Contributors @LucasKauffman @KyleSmith @smassey)

Answer (score 1):

It might be that your ISP is blocking that port as it's known as a HTTP backup port. You might want to consult with them first.

Comment: +1 for the idea but also tried running apache on port 53617 with the same results.